# How to hide/show checkbox in SmartFilterBar

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sapui5

I'm trying to hide/show one checkbox after first one is selected in SmartFilterBar in SAPUI5. It should be changing of property but I cannot figure out the correct code.
This is code in my XML inside SmartFilterBar:

```
<smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="checkbox1" label="{i18n>Processingwithoutdialog}" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" >
<smartFilterBar:customControl> 
<CheckBox />
</smartFilterBar:customControl> 
</smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration> 
<smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="checkbox4" label="{i18n>Restrictedprotocol}" visibleInAdvancedArea="true">
<smartFilterBar:customControl> 
<CheckBox editable="false" select="onSelect"/>
</smartFilterBar:customControl>
```

And my code in controller.js:

```
    onSelect : function(oEvent) {
     var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource();  
     var oSmartFilterBar = this.byId("smartFilterBar"); 
     if (oSmartFilterBar instanceof sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar) {  

    var oCustom = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("checkbox1");
    var oCustom2 = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("checkbox4");
    oCustom2.setEditable( !oCustom.getSelected() );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with this function or what calls it but I see an issue with

```
var oCustom = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("checkbox1").getChecked;
```

and then

```
   oCustom.onchange = function() {
      oCustom2.editable = this.checked ? false : true;
   }
```

oCustom is not the control but possibly the result of a function call missing it parenthesis.

So I think you need to start by making this change:

```
var oCustom = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("checkbox1")
```

Then you can ask things of the control, like:

```
oCustom2.setEditable( !oCustom.getSelected() );
```

The trick is then if this is called on the onSelect event so you will need to use the attachSelect to attach the function or if you can set the select event in the xml.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I'm close now. I attach onSelect function to checkbox. It works but not properly. I want to set property from editable="false" to editable ="true" of "checkbox4" when property in "checkbox1" selected is true. Another problem is that user can leave checked "checkbox4" and click again "checkbox1" and both checkboxes are checked even when the "checkbox4" is not editable anymore. I changed code in my question